# ajax is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have a web application and in this i am using ajax controls.
due to some problem i remove the reference of ajaxcontroltoolkit and reset the toolbox of visual studio. After some i again add reference of previous ajaxcontroltoolkit and add tab in visual studio toolbox.
Now problem is that when i insert the control of newly installed ajaxcontroltoolkit and run the webapplication the no event(which is in update panel) or no ajax validation fire.
so please help what should i do
lot of time i try and remove and add reference of ajaxcontroltoolkit but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually deleteing the AjaxToolkit.dll file from your Bin directory.